# rails4-autocomplete gem with active_admin and belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Could anyone tell me the correct way for this ?
I've got situation like this one:

```
   collection_action :autocomplete_order_zip_id, :method => :get
   controller do

     autocomplete :order, :zip_id do |item|
       render json: Zip.all
     end
```

And filter:

```
   filter :zip_id_contains, :as => :autocomplete, :url => '/admin/orders/autocomplete_order_zip_id',
     :label => "Search Email", :required => false,
     :wrapper_html => { :style => "list-style: none" }
```

How can I pass my own searching logic for autocomplete ? 
So I want customer to type ZIP name and system should find suggestions by zip_id in my order table.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the solution this way, so I've used the jquery select2 for input type="text" with ajax loading of information and my custom logic to get it.

Comment: Yeah, a year ago I did the same )